# @PropertySource("file:${env.variable.name}/file.properties") is not working on Windows

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, environment-variables, properties-file

I'm developing a spring-boot application which has externalized test configuration. I read the configuration file using `@PropertySource` annotation like this--
`@PropertySource("file:path-to-file-on-file-system/file.properties")`

If path is hardcoded, it works on both windows and linux systems however to make it configurable, I have created an environment variable that stores the absolute path to the file on the file system.

1. On Linux `export PROPS=/usr/local/config`
2. On Windows `System > Advanced System Settings > Advanced > Environment Variables > New System Variable > Name=PROPS & Value=C:/Users/Dev/Config`

And then `@PropertySource("file:${PROPS}/file.properties")`

This works seamlessly on Linux but throws exception on Windows systems as below

> Could not resolve placeholder 'PROPS' in string value
>   "file:${PROPS}/file.properties"

`echo %PROPS%` displays correct path on command line.

Any help to resolve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running in a new Command Prompt? After you change the ENV vars in Windows, you need to open a new terminal. Also you can try `set PROPS=C:/Users/Dev/Config`. Another reason could be the path. Try the linux style path `/c/users/Dev/Config`, you can confirm the path in gitbash.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I was running code in IDE. Restarting an IDE worked.

Comment: Pro Tip: You can set Environment variables in your IDE as well. Edit the Run Configuration, you'll see the option there.

Comment: Setting environment variables in IDE wasn't a problem. Script sets the value of environment variable in non dev environments